# Playframework 2.2.2 not working on windows 7 with scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I just downloaded playframework 2.2.2 and created new project with play new and chose simple scala appplication

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

$cd test

$test>play
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\JJ-Solutions\test\project
[info] Set current project to test (in build file:/C:/Users/JJ-Solutions/test/)
       _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |
|  __/|_|\____|\__ /
|_|            |__/

play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0_05), http://www.playframe
work.com

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[test] $
```

When I run play run command. I get this error message when using `http://localhost:9000` I get error: The compilation failed without reporting any problem!

```
$play run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\TestUser\test\project
[info] Set current project to play (in build file:/C:/Users/JJ-Solutions/test/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/JJ-Solutions/test/}test...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-jdbc_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-link;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.javassist#javassist;3.18.0-GA ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#templates_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-file_2.10;0.4.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.github.scala-incubator.io#scala-io-core_2.10;0.4.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.jsuereth#scala-arm_2.10;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-iteratees_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-stm#scala-stm_2.10;0.7 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe#config;1.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-functional_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-datacommons_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.3.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-annotations;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-core;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.fasterxml.jackson.core#jackson-databind;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving io.netty#netty;3.7.0.Final ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.netty#netty-http-pipelining;1.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jul-to-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.slf4j#jcl-over-slf4j;1.7.5 ...
  [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-core;1.0.13 ...
  [info] Resolving ch.qos.logback#logback-classic;1.0.13 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-actor_2.10;2.2.0 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.akka#akka-slf4j_2.10;2.2.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-lang3;3.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.ning#async-http-client;1.7.18 ...
  [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-core;1.2.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving oauth.signpost#signpost-commonshttp4;1.2.1.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving xerces#xercesImpl;2.11.0 ...
  [info] Resolving xml-apis#xml-apis;1.4.01 ...
  [info] Resolving javax.transaction#jta;1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.jolbox#bonecp;0.8.0.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving com.google.guava#guava;14.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.h2database#h2;1.3.172 ...
  [info] Resolving tyrex#tyrex;1.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#anorm_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-cache_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sf.ehcache#ehcache-core;2.6.6 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-test_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving junit#junit;4.11 ...
  [info] Resolving org.hamcrest#hamcrest-core;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.specs2#specs2_2.10;2.1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-core_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-concurrent_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scalaz#scalaz-effect_2.10;7.0.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.novocode#junit-interface;0.10 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-tools.testing#test-interface;0.5 ...
  [info] Resolving com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;2.0.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-festassert;0.8.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fluentlenium#fluentlenium-core;0.8.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-java;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-android-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-remote-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving cglib#cglib-nodep;2.1_3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.json#json;20080701 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-api;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-exec;1.1 ...
  [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving net.java.dev.jna#platform;3.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-chrome-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-htmlunit-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit;2.12 ...
  [info] Resolving xalan#xalan;2.7.1 ...
  [info] Resolving xalan#serializer;2.7.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpmime;4.2.3 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.htmlunit#htmlunit-core-js;2.12 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.nekohtml#nekohtml;1.9.18 ...
  [info] Resolving net.sourceforge.cssparser#cssparser;0.9.9 ...
  [info] Resolving org.w3c.css#sac;1.3 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-websocket;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.9.v20130131 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-firefox-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-ie-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-iphone-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-safari-driver;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.webbitserver#webbit;0.4.14 ...
  [info] Resolving org.seleniumhq.selenium#selenium-support;2.32.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-assert;1.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.easytesting#fest-util;1.1.6 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-docs_2.10;2.2.2 ...
  [info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#play-doc_2.10;1.0.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.pegdown#pegdown;1.4.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-java;1.1.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.parboiled#parboiled-core;1.1.5 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-tree;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-analysis;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.ow2.asm#asm-util;4.1 ...
  [info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.4 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.3 ...
  [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 5 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\Users\TestUser\test
\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.10.3. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 10.405 s
[error] Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -

! @6i3ag10ga - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.PlayExceptions$UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[The compilation fa
iled without reporting any problem!]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfu
n$apply$17.apply(PlayReloader.scala:306) ~[na:na]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14$$anonfu
n$apply$17.apply(PlayReloader.scala:306) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(P
layReloader.scala:305) ~[na:na]
        at play.PlayReloader$$anon$1$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(P
layReloader.scala:298) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
sbt.compiler.CompileFailed: null
        at sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$JavaTool0.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:77) ~[
na:na]
        at sbt.compiler.JavaTool$class.apply(JavaCompiler.scala:35) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$JavaTool0.apply(JavaCompiler.scala:63) ~[na
:na]
        at sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$class.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:21) ~[na:n
a]
        at sbt.compiler.JavaCompiler$JavaTool0.compile(JavaCompiler.scala:63) ~[
na:na]
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$1.ap
ply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:126) ~[na:na]
[warn] play - No application found at invoker init
```

Any idea what would be causing this?

I've added play folder to system environment variables and also I've JAVA_HOME at Path variable.

I've Windows 7 x64 and Oracle JDK 8

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Java setup is not entirely correct which is indicated by these two lines in your log:

```
[error] Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

It means that the Main class could not be found. It is located in tools.jar, which should be in the `JAVA_HOME\lib` dir.

Re-check your Java installation and make sure all paths are set correctly. Try compiling a simple Java file first to make sure you can compile.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I reinstalled the JDK and I was also missing the lib from Path.